# Delta live tables in Databricks can take only one target

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

If I need to publish two tables in two different databases in the metastore, do I need to create two different DLT pipeline? I am asking this because I saw that in the pipeline setting, i can only specify 1 target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now - yes, DLT only supports one target database. So if you need to push into different databases, then you may have two DLT pipelines.

Theoretically you can have one pipeline that will be publishing two tables into a single database, and then you can use `create table ... using delta location '<dlt_storage>/tables/<table_name>'` to refer to it, but it won't work well with the schema evolution, etc.

Comment: Hi Alex, how will it impact schema evolution. Can you please help explain this.

Comment: Schema evolution will still work for Delta Live Tables, but the schema may not be reflected for a table in the 2nd database as it's not directly maintained by DLT